# Prevent PostgreSQL to start when Mac OS X boots

Tags: macos, mac, postgresql

I installed PostgreSQL 8.4.4 in Mac OS X. I am pretty happy and I don't want to uninstall it since I do occasional development on it.

But I would definitely like to prevent OS X to run it every time the machine boots up.

What's the "Mac OS way" of doing that? In Linux I would turn off the service in some runlevels, but I don't know how to do the same in **Mac OS X**.

Thanks!

Comment: To start, how did you install it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mac OS X uses `launchd` to replace `init.d`.

To disable a `launchd` job you need to find out the name of the plist that has all the details of the job. `sudo launchctl unload /PATH/TO/PLIST`.

The file is most likely in `/Library/LaunchDaemons` but the exact name depends on how you installed it (eg. PostgreSQL's distribution, MacPorts, etc.)